# How to remove an object from a listbox after a condition is reached

Tags: c#, forms, listbox, generic-list

I have a generic list of employees, I want to remove them from the listbox after a certain condition is reached.

Currently I have managed to get a close form of it working but if there's more than one object in the list box it gets duplicated after the methods are ran.

- Each employee has a `shifts left` variable, if this ends they are transported back into the `free` list

---

```
private void btnCycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Employee emp in employees)
    {
        if (emp.Busy == true)
        {
            emp.ShiftsLeft--;
            if (emp.ShiftsLeft == 0)
            {
                lstOccupied.Items.Clear();
                emp.Busy = false;
                DisplayData(employees);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void DisplayData(List<Employee> employees)
{
    foreach (Employee emp in employees)
    {
        if (emp.Busy == false)
            lstFree.Items.Add(emp);
        else if (emp.Busy == true)
            lstOccupied.Items.Add(emp);
    }
}
```

---

This is the objects in use at the minute

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name", MemberSkills.CPlus, true,
    "Do this Job", 5);

Employee e2 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Another name", MemberSkills.CSharp, true,
    "Do another Job", 2);
```

**Outcome**

What currently happens with the code that I have provided is that after `Another name` is finished with their shift (2 shifts) they are transported back into the `free` listbox, and they disappear from the `occupied` listbox, which is what I wanted, then after `Name` is finished they get placed back into `free` but `another name` is displayed twice.

**Possible Solution**

I could have it so that if the name is displayed more than once on the `free` it gets removed and only displayed once, but this is messy and I can imagine if an employee has the same name as another this would cause conflicts.

Comment: The right way of saying `if (emp.Busy == false) lstFree.Items.Add(emp); else if (emp.Busy == true) lstOccupied.Items.Add(emp);` is `if (emp.Busy) lstOccupied.Items.Add(emp); else lstFree.Items.Add(emp);`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yeah I didn't even notice that till you pointed it out, I probs would have neatened up my code towards the end of the program but thanks for pointing it out and keeping it uniform standard :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finish the logical work of the first loop without attempting to update the lists while you are still running the loop. At the end of the loop DisplayData after clearing both lists.

```
private void btnCycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Employee emp in employees)
    {
        if (emp.Busy)
        {
            emp.ShiftsLeft--;
            emp.Busy = emp.ShiftsLeft > 0;
            // Do not try to update here
            // finish the logic loop and...
        }
    }
}

// Clear the content of both lists
lstFree.Items.Clear();
lstOccupied.Items.Clear();

// Now rebuild both lists
DisplayData(employees);
```

If you want to remove the double loop over the employees list you could clear the two listboxes before starting the first loop and readd the entries as soon as you could determine the busy status of each employee

```
private void btnCycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear the content of both lists
    lstFree.Items.Clear();
    lstOccupied.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Employee emp in employees)
    {
        if (emp.Busy)
        {
            emp.ShiftsLeft--;
            if (emp.ShiftsLeft == 0)
            {
                lstFree.Items.Add(emp);
                emp.Busy = false;
            }
            else
                lstOccupied.Items.Add(emp);
        }
    }
}
```

Of corse you don't call anymore DisplayData in this context.